# Is there a Ruby gem that can generate an API for Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sinatra

We have a big Rails app and we're looking to extract our User model out into an API to move to a more service oriented architecture. Right now we're creating the API on a small Sinatra app that can handle all User-related requests. My question is: does anyone know of a Ruby gem (that works with Rails or Sinatra) that brings in a lot of standard API functionality?

I want to make sure I'm not re-inventing the wheel here. Other than standard RESTful routing, we're looking for functionality like sending a route specific attributes on an object that you want returned (instead of always returning the full object). Is there a gem out there that does this or is it better to just create our own from scratch? If I did a poor job explaining anything, let me know and I can clarify.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3):

You might find https://github.com/nesquena/rabl useful. I built it for all my RESTful API needs in Sinatra, Padrino and rails.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure you would go for it but I'd give a try to [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) if I were you.